# Lightswitch 2013 HTML Client and multi user development environment

Tags: port, conflict, lightswitch-2013, multi-user

I have a server where some people can connect remotely and work simultaneously. My colleague and I are developing an "lightswitch 2013 html" application but we can not work simultaneously because IIS uses the same port (2057), both for me and for my colleague and this creates conflicts. How can I change my port in a Lightswitch HTML Application Project?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- close the solution
- use a text editor to open [YourLSApp].Server.csproj
- change values for `<DevelopmentServerPort>` and `<IISUrl>`

see also: https://xpert360.wordpress.com/2013/10/04/specify-ports-after-upgrading-lightswitch-html-clients-to-vs2013/